# getting round average in laravel way

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to run average in my project but I was not able to make the round function work, every time I run the function I always end up with float value example: average is 86.5, I wanted it to round to nearest tens which is 87 or if lower it will turn 86.

**Controller**

```
$score->average =round( $row['result1'] + $row['result2']) /2;
```

**Schema**

```
 $table->integer('result1');
 $table->integer('result2');
```

Comment: use this round( ($row['result1'] + $row['result2'])/2);
divide by 2 may not give integer always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this one

```
$score->average =round( ($row['result1'] + $row['result2']) /2) ;
```

using this will apply the PEMDAS rule.

Hope it helps

Comment: this is working thanks you sir, can i add follow up question, how to ignore RESULT1 if null like the way excel works when its null value it will skip.

Comment: you can use `if(!empty($value);`

Comment: if you're using php 7+ you can try this `$score->average =round( ($row['result1'] ?? '0' + $row['result2'] ?? '0') /2) ;` if the result 1 is empty then it will put 0 and if the result 2 is 0 it will put 0 too

Answer (score 1):

You can get integer value like this:

```
$score->average = (int)round(($row['result1'] + $row['result2']) /2);
```

Since, round function returns floating point value like 3.0, 45.0 so to get integer you have to type case the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$summation = $row['result1'] + $row['result2'];
$divideRslt = $summation / 2;

$score->average =round($divideRslt);
```